# fast way to compute the following product

Tags: performance, algorithm, optimization, matrix, time-complexity

Given

1) a `1xn` vector `a`,

2) a `nx1` vector `b`,

3) a `nxn` matrix `X`,

the problem is to obtain an iterative method that can compute the product

`a*{X*{X*{X*X}*X}*X}*b`

as fast as possible, where the bracket `{Y}` is a user-defined operator that returns a matrix whose all diagonal elements are all zero and whose off-diagonal elements are equal to those of matrix `Y`.

---

**NOTE:**

Without the bracket `{}` operator, if one wants to compute the product `a*X*X*X*X*X*X*b`, I think we can naturally associate the matrix multiplication operator `*` as follows:

`(((a*X)*X)*X)*(X*(X*(X*b)))`

so that the total time complexity is `O(n^2)`. However, when it comes to the computation of

`a*{X*{X*{X*X}*X}*X}*b`

I have no idea how to change the association sort of `*`. I would appreciate if someone could give me some hints to show the possibility of iteratively computing `a*{X*{X*{X*X}*X}*X}*b` in the same time of `O(n^2)`, not `O(n^3)`.

Comment: If n is (universal) constant, you can calculate the expression and use it directly.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem, `a*{X*{X*{X*X}*X}*X}*b = {{{{{{a*X}*X}*X}*X}*X}*X}*b`

Comment: @amit Is it the case that `{X*Y}*Z = X*{Y*Z}`?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes, matrix multiplication is [Associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property)

Comment: @amit The `{}` changes the matrices involved.  I don't think it's associative anymore.

Comment: @Teepeemm OK, now I get it. {} is not simply showing order of operations. thank you for clarifying, the question makes much more sense now. Knew I didn't understand the problem.

Comment: No, I have to mention that `{X*Y}*Z != X*{Y*Z}`, although the conventional matrix multiplication is associative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that we're going to come up with an `o(matrix-multiplication(n))`-time algorithm today, by the following reduction. It's possible to get the space usage to linear, though.

Let `{Y} = Y - diag(Y)`. I'm going to consider the simpler problem of computing `a*{X*{X*X}*X}*b'`. Using the linearity of `diag`, we write

```
{X*{X*X}*X} = {X*(X*X - diag(X*X))*X}
            = X*(X*X - diag(X*X))*X - diag(X*(X*X - diag(X*X))*X)
            = X*X*X*X - X*diag(X*X)*X - diag(X*X*X*X - X*diag(X*X)*X)
            = X*X*X*X - X*diag(X*X)*X - diag(X*X*X*X) + diag(X*diag(X*X)*X).
```

Now consider each term in turn. The first term, `a*X*X*X*X*b' = ((a*X)*X)*(X*(X*b'))`, is computable with `O(n^2)` operations. The second term, `a*X*diag(X*X)*X*b' = (a*X)*diag(X*X)*(X*b')`, is as well. So is the fourth term, `a*diag(X*diag(X*X)*X)*b'`.

The problematic term is the third, `a*diag(X*X*X*X)*b'`. Since the other three are computable with `O(n^2)` operations, it is equivalent in a sense to the whole computation.

Let `j` be the all-ones vector. Then `j*diag(X*X*X*X)*j' = tr(X^4)`. If `X` is the adjacency matrix of a graph, then `tr(X^4)` is the number of (possibly degenerate) 4-cycles. Assuming an undirected simple graph, the number of degenerate 4-cycles is given by a simple function of the degree sequence. The [state of the art in cycle counting](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19508/finding-number-of-cycles-of-length-k-in-a-graph) appears to be no better than matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm just wondering whether the reduction to the computation of 'tr(X^4)' is true or not. Since if 'j' is taken to be a unit vector, it seems the problem is computable with 'O(n^2)'.

Comment: @JohnSmith Enlighten me.